# Table Does not Wrap properly

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I tried to change my columns with p{unit} and also tried to use thead to get my final row in my table to wrap.  There is too much text and it runs of the page, causing some other text not to show.  Is there a way I can line break my last row?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[many,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\definecolor{ND1}{RGB}{12,35,64}
\definecolor{ND2}{RGB}{201,151,0}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5cm}

\begin{document}

%-------------------------HEADING------------------------
\tcbset{fonttitle=\bfseries}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,fill=blue!15](0,23)--(8.2,23)--(8.2,21)--(0,21)--cycle;
    \draw[thick,fill=blue!15](8.4,23)--(18.5,23)--(18.5,21)--(8.4,21)--cycle;
    \node[ellipse,draw,text=blue,fill=white] (e) at (10.75,22) {\LARGE{UNIT 6}};
    \node at (4,22.5){\Large{\textbf{Class Notes/}}};
    \node at (4.5,22){\Large{\textbf{Guided Practice}}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (13,22.6){\large{\textbf{Contextual}}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (13,21.85){\large{\textbf{Applications of}}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (13,21.3){\large{\textbf{Differentiation}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

%-------------------------LESSON SUMMARY------------------------
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
                \begin{tabular}[h]{|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{FUN} &   \cellcolor{ND2}AP Calculus BC   &   \cellcolor{ND2}Flint Hill Upper School  & \cellcolor{ND2}Mr. Bennett \\ \hline
                    \rowcolor{brown!50}\cellcolor{ND1}\textcolor{white}{4}&Topic 6.8& \thead{Finding Antiderivatives and \\ Indefinite Inetgrals: Basic Rules and Notation}     &   Day 1 \& 2 \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\cellcolor{ND2}{\textbf{Learning Objective CHA-6C: Determine antiderivatives of functions and indefinite integrals, using knowledge of derivatives}.}} \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. The Issue is in the Lesson Summary

Nick

Comment: Your last row really does need to be type `p`, but it's not going to break to a new page between lines unless you change it to a 'longtable`.  Also, please consider using `\raggedright` to keep the word spacing from getting too uneven.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton I will look at raggedright (I have not used it before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In image are use multipart shape, for table seems to be handy use the `tblr` of `tabularray` package where:

- for the third column is used `X` column type which enable automatic split long text into several lines:
- for last rows is used option `hspan=\minimal` which also enable to break text into several lines if it is longer than width of spanned columns (in this case the width of the table)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.geometric, shapes.multipart}
    \definecolor{ND1}{RGB}{12,35,64}
    \definecolor{ND2}{RGB}{201,151,0}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
%-------------------------HEADING------------------------
{\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt and 0.04\textwidth,
base/.style = {draw, thick, fill=blue!15, 
               inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, minimum height=24mm, 
               font=\Large\bfseries},
M/.style = {base,
            rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal,
            rectangle split draw splits=false, 
            %rectangle split empty part width=0.22\textwidth,
            text width = \dimexpr0.24\textwidth-0.5\pgflinewidth, align=center
            },
N/.style = {base, text width =\dimexpr0.48\textwidth-0.5\pgflinewidth, align=center},
                    ]
\node (n1) [N]  {Class Notes\\Guided Practice};
\node (n2) [M, right=of n1] 
                {\nodepart{two}   Contextual Applications of Differentiation};

\node[ellipse,draw, font=\Large, text=blue,fill=white] at (n2.mid) {UNIT 6};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%-------------------------LESSON SUMMARY------------------------
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c c X[c, m] c},
             row{1,3} =  {bg=ND1},
             row{1,3} =  {bg=ND2},
             cell{1,2}{1} = {bg=black,fg=white},
             cell{3}{1}   = {c=4}{l},
             hspan = minimal}

FUN & AP Calculus BC    & Flint Hill Upper School   & Mr. Bennett   \\
4   & Topic 6.8         & Finding Antiderivatives and Indefinite Integrals: Basic Rules and Notation 
                                                    & Day 1 \& 2    \\ 
Learning Objective CHA-6C: Determine antiderivatives of functions and indefinite integrals, using knowledge of derivatives.  
    &   &   &       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is amazing

Comment: @NickB, really? If it is, you can consider to upvote it (at least  )

Comment: I just reread above, figured out what to remove SMH

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: Instead of

```
\multicolumn{4}{l}{...}`
```

you should use

```
\mulicolumn{4}{p<usable width>}{...}
```

for the material in the final row. To determine the value of  `<usable width>`, I suggest you start with the full width of the text block (parameter `\textwidth`), *minus* the space taken up by the two vertical rules at either end (parameter: `\arrayrulewidth`), and *minus* the padding that LaTeX inserts at the left and right hand edges (parameter: `\tabcolsep`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
%% I've simplified the preamble as much as possible
\usepackage[margin=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\setlength{\columnsep}{5cm}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[many,skins]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ND1}{RGB}{12,35,64}
\definecolor{ND2}{RGB}{201,151,0}
\usepackage{calc} % <-- new, to simplify dimension calculations

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % optional, for a less-cramped look
%\centering % not needed
\begin{tabular}[h]{|c|c|c|c|} % LaTeX will determine width of fourth 'c' col. as a residual
\hline
\rowcolor{ND2}
\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{\bfseries FUN} &   
AP Calculus BC & Flint Hill Upper School & Mr.\ Bennett \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{brown!50}
\cellcolor{ND1}\textcolor{white}{\bfseries 4} &
Topic 6.8 & 
\thead{Finding Antiderivatives and \\ 
       Indefinite Integrals: Basic Rules and Notation}     
& Day 1 \& 2 \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{ND2}
\multicolumn{4}{|%
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{% % suppress justification and hyphenation
  \textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{% % calculate usable width
  \bfseries Learning Objective CHA-6C: Determine antiderivatives of
  functions and indefinite integrals, using knowledge of derivatives.} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```